# How to dynamically pass multiple classes to child component using CSS modules in React

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, webpack-style-loader

I am new to React.js. I am using CSS modules for styling and I want to dynamically pass multiple classes to a child component. Below is my code.

**Parent component**

Here I am passing **p-1 color-red** to child component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Demo from '../../shared/Demo';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
      headerClass: 'p-1 color-red'
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Demo headerClass={this.state.headerClass}>
      </Demo>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Child component**

Since, class name is dynamic and there are more than one classes I am not sure how to access it here. Below code is working if I have only one class in **headerClass**.

```
import React from "react";
import styles from './Demo.css';

const demo = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles[props.headerClass]}>{ props.title }</th>
  );
}

export default demo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the `headerClass` string property and concatenate all class names.

```
const demo = (props) => {
  const reducer = (acc, curr) => `${acc} ${styles[curr]}`;
  const className = props.headerClass.split(' ').reduce(reducer, '');
  return <div className={className}>{ props.title }</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. Is there any established way to use styles and classes that most of the react developers are following?